# Windows 7 : chose notepad++ uninstaller to "open with" once, now can't "open with" notepad++ anymore

Tags: windows-7, file-association

I've been struggling with a wrong file association I made a few days ago that I can't seem to remove.

What I wanted to do was opening a file that had an unknown extension with notepad++ so I right-clicked on it, then "open with". The usual popup opened up but NPP wasn't in the list.

Then I clicked on "browse" to select notepad++.exe but I wrongfully clicked on "uninstall.exe" (the NPP uninstaller) instead (which is right next to notepad++.exe...).

Since then, Windows added that uninstaller to the list of "open with" programs and I can't seem to replace it with the real NPP executable. If I browse again to notepad++.exe and select it, Windows just seems to think it's the same as "uninstaller.exe" and does NOT add it to the "open with" list.

So i'm stuck with that uninstaller which is absolutely useless and I can't associate any new extensions with NPP... Can anyone tell me how to reset that "open with" list ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : after uninstalling/reinstalling NPP, Windows remembers what it's old associations were and still uses the uninstaller as default instead of regular notepad++.exe...

Comment: @Biswapriyo I'm not sure I understand your question. Which .exe file are you referring to ? No file types were associated with uninstaller.exe, usual text files extensions were associated with notepad++.exe (.txt, .md, .log...) and the file I originally wanted to associate to NPP is a .diff file

Comment: OK but are you saying I'll need to do that each time I wanna associate a new extension to NPP ?

Comment: assoc & ftype do not seem to work for me : "assoc .diff" returns ".diff=txtfile" & "ftype txtfile" returns "txtfile="C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" but .diff file is still opened with default windows notepad, even after logout/login & reboot...

Comment: See [How to Remove Unwanted "Open with" menu Items in Windows](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/remove-unwanted-entries-open-with-menu-windows/)

Comment: YES, thank you @Win32Guy, "Remove Unwanted Items from “Open with” menu for ALL file types" did it for me ! Is there a way/Should I tag your comment as the accepted answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove an unwanted program from the Open with menu, use the following steps:

1. Start the Registry Editor (`regedit.exe`)
2. Go to the following location:

   > HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\uninstall.exe
3. Right-click on the uninstall.exe key and choose Delete
4. Exit the Registry Editor.

(via) [How to Remove Unwanted "Open with" menu Items in Windows](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/remove-unwanted-entries-open-with-menu-windows/)